# Windows 10 git push authentication password field does not allow any chanacters to be entered

Tags: windows, git, github, password-protection

I'm running Windows 10 latest update as of 2022-06-18. I have also installed the latest version of git. I have set up 2-factor authentication in GitHub and have created a personal access token.
When I execute:

```
git push origin main
```

I am asked for my username (which I am able to key in) and password. My understanding is that I need to enter my PAT in the password field, but it is not possible to enter any characters into the password field.

Does anyone know why the field is blocked?

Comment: When you're typing in the password field, it won't show feedback that you're typing, but it's still taking in your keystrokes.

Comment: Thanks for that. It did accept my very long PAT but only by using  paste from the command menu paste function., not with CTRL+V.

Comment: @Elliot: some password managers / software thingies deliberately try to disable cut and/or paste, so that you can't accidentally paste a password. I find this ... annoying, but understandable. :-)

Comment: @torek I hope I never have to type in my PAT. That would be seriously challenging to do without error!

Answer (score 1):

The alternative is to use the credential helper which is set (output of `git config --global credential.helper`)

With the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), it should be set to `manager-core`.
If note, type `git credential-manager-core configure`.

Type in a Git bash session:

```bash
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=You\npassword=YourToken" | \
  git credential-manager-core store
```

After that, Git/GitHub Desktop should not ask you for credentials.